# Is there a way to encourage people to comment on answers they don't like?

Tags: discussion

I've been seeing an increase in activity where answers are voted down without comment. I assume it's happening all over, but I only receive notifications when it happens on my own posts. A typical example is today when someone voted down my answer on [sen-, mal-, and ne-](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/when-is-the-prefix-ne-and-when-is-it-mal/2528#2528) which has stood for months with no concerns expressed.

If there is a concern about an answer given, an appropriate response would be to leave a short comment explaining what the concern is. That way people who come looking for answers can make an informed decision.

I suspect (but in no way know for sure) that this is being done by some newer members of the community who don't understand how Esperanto Stack Exchange is suposed to work. Is there any way to get this information out to users and encourage them to participate in the conversation rather than simply to vote an answer down if they don't like it or don't understand it?

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange already shows a message (*Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.*) to users who down-voted, when their reputation is lower than a threshold.

> [image: screenshot]

If a 10K user down-votes a post, though, there would not be any remainder.

Apart that, Stack Exchange never considered forcing users to leave a comment because that could be used to know the users who down-voted, and start a vote-revenge.
It would also force users to leave a comment when they don't have any comment. For example, they could agree with a previously given comment; in this case, a new comment would not add anything, especially because they can up-vote the previous comment, if they agree with it.